# Flask "redirect(url_for)" and "@login_required" error with nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, raspberry-pi, webserver

I made a web app hosted on my raspberry pi and I'm trying to get access to it from the internet. I am using Dataplicity (https://docs.dataplicity.com/docs/host-a-website-from-your-pi) to get access to my server using nginx.

Locally, everything works perfectly. I would launch the app with

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Go to my pi address in my browser with either port 8000 or 80 and successfully get the homepage of my app. Until there, the process works just as well on dataplicity.

The problem arise when I invoke the redirect(url_for) function (including @login_required). As soon as I invoke it through dataplicity, I get '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'.

When I work locally (or externally with port forwarding -> this leads me to think the problem lies with Dataplicity and nginx), I see the following GET request when I try to access my /camera view function without first being logged in to the app:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2019 22:27:47] "GET /camera HTTP/1.0" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2019 22:27:47] "GET /login?next=%2Fcamera HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

When I try to access it through dataplicity, I only get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2019 22:28:37] "GET /camera HTTP/1.0" 302 -
```

The : "GET /login?next=%2Fcamera HTTP/1.0" 200 - being absent.

If this can help, every url in dataplicity shows as https, except when I hit a redirect(url_for) or a @login_requested function, it turns to http.

I have tried several different nginx configurations I found on Stack Overflow and I also tried to tweak them a little bit by reading the documentation. This was in vain. I won't share them, as all the variations I tried were leading to the same effect.

Here is my actual nginx configuration :

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name _;
        access_log /var/log/app_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/app_error.log;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Here is the significant code in my app :

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Cat')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

@app.route("/camera")
@login_required
def stream():
    templateData = {
        'title' : "Stream"
    }
    return render_template('camera.html', **templateData)
```

I wish to get the same experience externally (through dataplicity because I don't like the idea of opening my ports) as the one I get locally. That is, being able to use my 'login' view function without bumping into errors every time I get redirected.

## Update:

My app is finally functional. The answer was, I think, Gunicorn. I had the following `supervisor` file that I was barely testing because I wasn't getting any clear feedback from it :

```
[program:app]
command=/var/www/html/app/sandbox/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 ...
directory=/var/www/html/app/
user=pi
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

Today, after trying one too many time, the app just worked when I reloaded `supervisorctl`. I still have to find out what makes this specific nginx config only work when Gunicorn is running.

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000` is still not working.

`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4 app:app` is working.

Comment: Did you try with `proxy_redirect on;` ?

Comment: Hi Alex, `on` is not a valid parameter for `proxy_redirect`. I have tried `default` and `off` and neither of them has an influence on my problem.